# JQuery parseJSON Tweet ID rounded up Problem and Solution

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I was using JQuery's $.getJSON to retrieve a list of tweets and for an unknown reason some of the tweet id(s) were being rounded 
`"id": 34903960418516968,` to `"id": 34903960418516970,`
So instead I tried using $.ajax with dataType: "text", and then did the conversion to JSON via **parseJSON, JSON.parse and eval which did not work**.
The only solution that I found was to make the datatype of the ID String instead of Number while the JSON source is still in text format. I surrounded the actual ID with double quotes " and I used the following regular expression to do that.

```
data = data.replace(/\"id\": (\d{15,}),/gi, "\"id\": \"$1\",");
```

ajax call

```
$.ajax({
         async: true,
         url: tweetsUrl,
         dataType: "text",
         success: getTweetsResult
       });
```

the getTweetsResult

```
function getTweetsResult(data, textStatus, xhr){
    //remove trailing ,
    data = data.substring(0, data.lastIndexOf(",]")) + "]";
    //convert tweet.id to string because the eval of JS is rounding up some of the number
    data = data.replace(/\"id\": (\d{15,}),/gi, "\"id\": \"$1\",");
    //console works with Chrome
    //  console.log(data);
    var tweetList = $.parseJSON(data);
    generateTweets("tweets", "tweetGrid", tweetList, 3, tweets);
    applyRollOverGridItems();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember reading on the twitter blog that the twitter ID data type had changed and that developers had to update their code. If I remember correctly, they now send the ID as a string variable as well as a long (or float, not sure which) variable. Have a look at the response, and get the ID from the string variable. Should solve that issue.

EDIT: Found the URLS

http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/6a16efa375532182?pli=1

http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/10/19/the-twitter-id-shuffle-text-vs-numbers/

Comment: Double checking I found that the tweets in JSON do contain a field for the id in string named id_str. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Just open the .csv in TextEdit instead of in Excel. Excel will round numbers with more than 15 digits but TextEdit will leave the numbers as is

Comment: The OP is reading data programmatically, not opening the file in an editor.

Comment: This looks like you haven't read the OP - he is opening it via JSON/Jquery with a browser not Excel

Comment: And the OP is not dealing with CSV (comma-separated values) data.